# AWS SAM - Hello World + custom IAM role name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam

I follow [this AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-getting-started-hello-world.html) to create a Hello World example deployment. The YAML template is very simple, defines a Lambda function + some outputs. When I deploy, AWS SAM is creating an IAM role with AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole policy attached. In trust relationships, it allows lambda.amazonaws.com sts:AssumeRole. The role is not defined within the project, and it's default name looks like this:

stackset_name-HelloWorldFunctionRole-some_random_string

I would like to know if that role is created every time SAM deploys a project and if there's a way to control the role's name and attach permission boundaries to it.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the documentation in step three (2.d) there is an option to allow creation of the IAM role. From looking at the example output the name of the role is specific to the application, so if role creation is allowed it will create one for each application. Doesn’t seem to be a way to specify the name etc, If you want to control this you’ll have to create it separately and not allow the automatic creation. Hope that helps!

Comment: No, that's not the case. The default role gets created even if I answer "n" to that question.